# Why are rep and badges now collapsed on Safari iPad?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar, ipad

This is the right edge of my topbar, starting today:

[image: No reputation.]

Any particular reason why I'm not seeing my total reputation and badges there? Since it's a major part of the "gamification" setup, am I correct in thinking it's a bug? Is it exclusive to Safari iOS?

Update: I highly doubt it's my viewport, since there's plenty of space for it:

[image: full topbar]

If this *is* a viewport problem, why is there so much space for it?

Comment: Reproduced, but only when I narrow the browser window to less than about a third of my screen width.

Comment: @RobertLongson - No, normally between the inbox and the usericon, the rep and the badge count is shown.

Comment: Probably  part of the responsive design efforts.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin confirmed. With a small width browser, it does not display.

Comment: I noticed it is at 980 pixels of width... can anyone prove this?

Comment: It'll be hard for me to test - viewport resolution takes into account DPI, so even though my screen resolution is 1920x1080, I use 125% DPI so my viewport resolution is 1536x864.

Comment: It looks like you are on an ipad. Are you on landscape orientation? If you are, I would have to say this is a bug. In response to your question "why is there so much space for it": They are probably using breakpoints to establish when to hide rep. And breakpoints are fixed.

Comment: @KodosJohnson yeah, iPad on landscape, same device I usually use.

Comment: I would have to argue in favor of this being caused by viewport. If you went on a desktop computer and resized your browser, you would see that the reputation is disappearing and reappearing when you resize it. Maybe you should add ipad as one of your tags.

Comment: The problem appears to be that the top-bar is set up for responsive but the page itself isn't (no viewport set), so the default iOS viewport width of 980 kicks in.  Since the text is set to hide at max-width: 980px, it disappears.  It should probably be `max-width: 979px`.

Comment: Welcome to Responsive Layout. I'm pretty sure it's how the site is meant to look like, and lots more of those changes are to come.

Comment: My phone has a WQHD (2960x1440) screen. Yesterday I could see my Avatar, Rep, and badges. Now just my Avatar shows. Probably mobile-discriminatory.

Comment: @BrianNickel & Pawel, this now [works correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE1Qu.png) on my phone, fixed in the past hour.

Answer (score 6):

The reputation and badges are hidden in narrower viewports (i.e. if your browser window is narrower).

Narrow window:

[image: Rep, badges, and search box hidden]

Middle-width window:

[image: Same as before, but search box visible (text inside is smaller than below)]

Wide window:

[image: Full top bar visible]

Comment: This just started today, and it's been showing before, so I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: @StephenLeppik I proved it on a seperate device... so it seems it is correct.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Likely they altered the threshold for collapsing. But this collapsing behavior has existed for a while (I see it if I snap my window to half of the screen).

Comment: It looks like another change is that the search bar disappears but shows up in a dropdown if you click the magnifying glass.

Comment: that (search engine disappearing) occurs for me at 640 pixels...

Comment: Looks like OP is using ipad on landscape orientation so I would have to say that this is a bug since I don't think they should hide it.

Comment: On my phone (Nexus 6P) I could see my rep on the screen when the browser was full screen until today. So while this may be true now, it wasn't always true. Did something change to make this true now?