# Also show reputation and badges on review subpages

Tags: feature-request, reputation, review, top-bar

The answer to the question "[Why are rep and badges now collapsed on Safari iPad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309242/286501)" explains that for narrower viewports, your reputation and badges are not shown in your topbar. As a sample, in my case, the reputation is shown if I'm using a landscape view on my mobile device, while it is not shown if I'm using a portrait view (i.e. if I flip my device 90°). So ar so good ...

... Euh, well, not really ... I noticed this variation on the `/review` page and its related subpages, for all sites that use the new site theme (such as SO, SU, SF, Meta, beta sites, etc), and this all related to the horizontal views:

- on `/review` pages, my reputation and badges are shown (works as designed).
- on any subpage of the `/review` page, such as `/review/que/stats`,  `/review/que/history` and  `/review/que/reviewid` (the actual review of some post), my reputation and badges are NOT shown, and this for any of the typical values of `que` (first post, late answers, etc).

**Request**: also show my reputation and badges on these subpages of the  `/review` page (there is plenty of room, so why hide it ...).

PS: using a Browser on my PC, those review subpages are shown including my reputation and badges (so I cannot recreate the same issue there).

Comment: I noticed this too, but I thought they simply didn't get to making these pages responsive yet. The [tour] page suffers from the same problem.